# Hierarchical List of All tables

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL Server DB, I have to find all the "Master"(Parent) tables and also build a
Hierarchical list of Paerent/Child tables. Finally I would like to traverse that hierarchical
list from down and delete all the child table data at the end i can able to delete
the parent data also.
I have tried in one way, that is, Using system tables (like sys.objects etc) I
queried the metadata of the db (like its primary and Foreign keys). But I don't know how
to formulate the tree like structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in `SQL Server Management Studio`:

```
EXEC sp_msdependencies @intrans = 1
```

if you insert the results into a temp table, you could then filter it to be just tables, just views, or use the other, alternative parameters for the proc to do the same thing

```
EXEC sp_msdependencies @intrans = 1 ,@objtype=8  --8 = tables
EXEC sp_msdependencies @intrans = 1 ,@objtype=3  --3 = tables is the correct one
```

Check this for more [Heirarchical](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1081916-392-1.aspx)